# how to solve this boolean algrbra expression

Tags: boolean-expression, digital-logic

I would like help simplifying this boolean algebra expression:

B*C + ~A*~B + ~A*~C => A*B*C + ~A

I need to know the steps of how to simplify it to the ABC + ~A

'*' indicates "AND"

'+' indicates "OR"

"~A" indicates "A NOT"

Any help would be appreciated! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For a better view, i'll skip `*` for conjunction, and use `'` for negation.

First you shall expand the 2 term disjunctions: Expand `B*C` , `A'*B'` and `A'*C'`

**1)** `(A + A')BC + A'B'(C + C') + A'(B + B')C'`

now distribute the parentheses.

**2)** `ABC + A'BC + A'B'C + A'B'C' + A'BC' + A'B'C'`

the fourth term and the last term are the same, `A'B'C'`, so ignore one of them since `p + p = p` or you can expand the situation for your needs (might be needed for some situations) as in `p+p+p+p+....+p = p`

**3)** So now, lets try to search for common terms. See the 2nd term and 5th term, `A'BC` and `A'BC'`. Take common parenthesis, `A'B(C+C') => A'B`.
Do the same for 3rd term and the 4th term, `A'B'C` and `A'B'C'`. `A'B'(C+C') => A'B'` since `X+X' = 1`.

now we have:

`ABC + A'B + A'B'`

**4)** take common parenthesis again, 2nd and 3rd term: `A'(B+B')`

There you have `ABC + A'`

`BC + A'B' + A'C' => ABC + A'`